# Ubuntu 14.04 starting issue after official upgrade from 12.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have a Dell Vostro 2520 model laptop which came with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS preloaded in it. I have upgraded officially to 14.04 LTS from the upgrade settings in my laptop. After the upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 is running but I always have to go to recovery mode and after that only I am able to use my laptop. If I do not go to recovery mode then on the start screen commands are running. The screen blinks continuously (commands are starting and stopping but some are not visible).

I had tried boot repair disk from command line in active session by following the instructions from help but not got any solution yet.
Please help me. I am a new  Ubuntu user but love it so much don't wanna shift to Windows 8.

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms? What means "continiously ...starting.... stoppping... like this !!!"? And what's a lapi? You can edit the question to refine it.

Comment: i would create a bootable usb or cd of my preferred ubuntu flavour ([in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) or [in Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)) and test in a live session if booting from there i get the same results. if the same happens, then it might be a problem with the drivers. if not, i would reinstall the system from the same cd or usb

Comment: sometime it reads in starting that "reading btrfs file systems" when it comes on start then normal boot happens but now its not coming.I had edited too my question.plz help any experts here.Thanks.

Comment: Dear @cipricus plz **help** me !!!

Comment: I am not an expert, not at all. It is not impossible that an expert will answer you, but first of all try to express very clearly what is happening. If that is not clear to you, it is even less clear to others. Your comments seem written in haste. Hardware issues may be involved. Have you booted from a live cd? Not trying to repair, just boot from the live cd or usb and use the 'test' option. What happens then?

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer but an advice...
Downloading new version ISO image and making a BootDVD is better than Upgrading directly from lower versions to new ones.
Because, The Upgrade you do in your ubuntu takes more time to download an install all the package repositories you've currently installed in your ubuntu.
And that process downloads the applications you've currently installed even it doesn't requires an update !
So the time is wasting there.
And there are lot of other problems too.
The problem may have a reason of your internet connection too..
If your connection lags a little while the downloading going on, Then it will cause the upgrade process to miss installing some files from downloading !!!
So you should have experienced this problem.
Your internet connection cheated you !
So I prefer you to download Ubuntu ISO image and Burn it into a DVD.Then install Ubuntu's new version with it !
Thats safe and better than the internet upgrade !
And also one more problem with internet upgrade : The time you've spend for the upgrade will be wasted and useless if your computer gets to crash or repair !!!
You can download the Ubuntu iso file by [clicking here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

But I prefer you to use torrent download to download it without spenting much time !
Go to torrents page  : 
**[Click here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)**

Answer (score 0):

Check this [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553329/failed-to-start-session?noredirect=1#comment758855_553329) link, we had a discussion yesterday with Harmeet, a long one. At the moment we are chatting on FB and I'm guiding him how re-partition, create, install etc..

We didn't manage to find a solution to repair it. Also installing gnome shell didn't help booting to a working desktop. Installing graphics drivers and resetting lightdm/unity were hopeless guesses.

Maybe you are my first candidate to try out my new `sudo` [code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553640/creating-a-sudo-code-prior-installing-all-necessary-software) to install most common programs after a clean reinstall ;)

Comment: plz chk boot prob details : http://paste.ubuntu.com/9551262/

Comment: Your system is providing 3D via software rendering rather than hardware rendering.  This is a compatibility mode which should display 3D graphics properly but the performance may be very poor.  If the problem you're reporting is related to graphics performance, your real question may be why X didn't use hardware acceleration for your system.

Comment: When booting from live usb ,the same problem is faced as booting fron hard disk.plz help